# Categorical variable with a lot of levels and interaction

Tags: interaction, many-categories

Suppose we have a categorical variable $X_1$ with $100$ levels. Should we **not** test interaction between $X$ and some other variable $X_2$?

Because if, for example, $X_1(3)*X_2$ is not significant then the interaction between $X_1$ and $X_2$ is not significant?

Comment: You should almost certainly *not* have a categorical variable with 100 levels.

Comment: Also, just because *one* level of the interaction is not significant does *not* mean that the whole thing is not significant.
But it would be better if you  could give some context. What are these variables? What sort of model are you running? How much data have you got? etc.

Comment: Why can we not have 100 categories, Peter?  For example, if I have an $(x,y,z)$ dataset of, say, 10000 cases, then one way I might assess the relationship between $x$ and $(y,z)$ would be to slice $x$ into 100 bins and explore how the empirical distribution of $(y,z)$ varies from bin to bin.  Or perhaps I'm studying the geographic distribution of $(y,z)$ and $x$ indicates an administrative data-collection unit such as a Census tract: there are tens of thousands of those in the US, for instance. Your "certainly not" may be correct from a narrow specialized viewpoint but is not generally true.

Comment: Hi @whuber Well, that's why I said "almost" :-). 

And also why, in my second comment I asked for context.

Answer (score 3):

I upvoted @Peter Flom's comment that you generally shouldn't have a categorical variable with 100 levels.

But if you *do* (I am thinking of a situation where maybe $X_1$ is, for example, the 140 or so commonwealth electorates in Australia, and for some reason you are interested in the variable's impact as a bunch of individually important areas with fixed effects rather than as a distribution of random effects in a mixed-effects model), it is quite appropriate to test its interaction with some other variable $X_2$.  But you must do it by an F test that tests the value of the whole interaction term (with its 100 degrees of freedom), not just whether one level of  $X_1$ is related.

You don't need every level of $X_1$ to have a different value of the parameter in front of  $X_2$ for the overall interaction to be important.  In testing for significance, you certainly should *not* be looking at any t-statistics such as for the estimate of the coefficient in front of $X_1(3)*X_2$

Comment: Or you could have some form of limited interaction model, that is, not a completely general interaction term, but a limited functional form.  That could make the model non-linear, though. Or, using fused lasso with extra penalty on the interaction terms ...